# how do I keep adding more than one element to a div by clicking a HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have been working on a **ToDo** app and I have managed to create a task by clicking a button, the thing is that I want it to keep creating tasks as `createButton` is clicked but it only does it once. how could I get to keep creating tasks

```
//inputs
let ids1 = document.getElementById('ids')
let ids2 = document.getElementById('ids2')
let ids3 = document.getElementById('ids3')
let ids4 = document.getElementById('ids4')

//create paragraph
let paro = document.createElement('p')

let createButton = document.getElementsByClassName('create')
let newd = document.getElementsByClassName('newd')

function createTask (){ 

paro.innerText = ids1.value + ' ' + ids2.value + ' ' + ids3.value + ' ' + ids4.value

if(ids1.value !== ''){ 
    if(ids2.value !== ''){ 
        if(ids3.value !== ''){ 
            newd[0].appendChild(paro)
        }else {
            alert('date is required')
        }

    }else {
        alert('description description is required')
    }
}else {
     alert('title is required')
}
}


 createButton[0].addEventListener('click', createTask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `<p>` element inside the `createTask` event handler, so that you are creating a new element each time instead of appending the same element.

Demo:

```js
let ids1 = document.getElementById('ids')
let ids2 = document.getElementById('ids2')
let createButton = document.querySelector('.create');
let newd = document.querySelector('.newd');

function createTask() {
  let paro = document.createElement('p');
  paro.innerText = ids1.value + ' ' + ids2.value;
  newd.appendChild(paro);
}
createButton.addEventListener('click', createTask);
```

```html
<input id="ids"> <input id="ids2">
<button class="create">Create</button>
<div class="newd"></div>
```